Linearity of differential equation including $\frac{y'}{y}$.
Is the following linear or non-linear?
$$\frac{y'}{y}-3x=1.$$
I am confused because when I multiply both sides by $y$, the equation changes to
$$y'-3xy-y=0.$$
The result seems linear.
However, before multiplying by $y$, I am unsure whether the equation is linear or not.
Could someone clarify and explain this to me?
To determine the linearity of a given differential equation, should I rearrange the equation first?
Many thanks.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

$x+(1/x)=17$ is a quadratic equation, even though it isn't written in the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$, because it can be rewritten in that form. Same for $(y'/y)-3x=1$ not looking linear, but it is linear, because it can be rewritten in linear form.

A very cumbersome way of showing that the original ODE is linear is to start with two solutions:
\begin{align}
\frac {y'}y-3x&=1\,,&\frac {z'}z-3x&=1
\end{align}
Then their sum satisfies the same ODE:
\begin{align}
\frac {y'+z'}{y+z}=\frac{y'y}{y(y+z)}+\frac{z'z}{z(y+z)}=\frac{(1+3x)y+(1+3x)z}{y+z}=1+3x\,.
\end{align}
